# HAproxy redirect with path rewrite based on refer code

Tags: regex, haproxy, http-redirect

I am trying to rewrite a URL from what it is currently in HAproxy:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/blog/Display.html?id=1262`

to

`https://blog.mywebsite.com/profile/old-1262/`

Unfortunately when I use this:

`http-request redirect code 302 location https://blog.mywebsite.com/profile/old-%[capture.req.uri,regsub(/blog/Display.html?id=,)]/`

I get redirected to the root of the website and it appears the content of regsub is empty.

Has anyone a good idea as to the correct syntax that I am missing to get the redirect to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I was quite close. I studied the examples in the manual more closely and I came to this:

```
 http-request set-uri https://blog.mywebsite.com/profile/old-%[query,regsub(id=,,g)]
```

And it gets me where I want to go.